# Software that can stream a website URL to YouTube

Tags: linux, streaming, bash

Software that can render a URL and stream to YouTube.

I have a web app that shows me some dynamic data over time.
I have a headless Linux VPS somewhere.

My guess on a possible solution is:
Open virtual x11 display with 1K dimensions
Run the index.html from Firefox full screen into the virtual display.
Use FFMPEG software to screen capture the virtual screen and stream it to YouTube.

There could be many possible ways to do this task.

Please recommend your solutions!

Comment: A different solution,  have you consider storage the information in database and using a graphing solution like graphana or similar to graph the data.  Then you can graph between any time frames of your choosing.  Then you won't have to stream a lot of data unnecessarily.